# Slow system after killing of an OOM process

Tags: ram, memory-usage

When a running application became out of memory and being killed by the kernel or the user, the system remains slow for a long time. The top is not showing any process with high CPU or memory load. I used to reset the machine to get rid of this slowness.

Any better way to normalize system speed?
Thank you

Comment: When an application goes OOM, memories of the other running but inactive apps move to swap partition AND remained there even after killing of OOM process. Those apps behave very slowly because first, their memory pages in swap have to get back to active memory. Turning swap off and then on, resolve the issue. Though it takes a long time to off and then on the swap in this scenario, it may be better than resetting the system.